# fitting student distribution with scale parameter

Tags: r

I have below x and y value and as you see x is mostly negative, basically I only have the left side of the PDF of my observed data.

I have to fit it with a student distribution, and find out the degree of freedom and scale parameter.

The problem is, the estimated distribution is gonna have a very small variance (ie. small scale parameter). So when I use the below method to fit the distribution, the nls fails to converge no matter what initial values I set.

I have used an extra parameter c in the below code because I scale the distribution by using this: `dt(x/a,df)`. Therefore, in order to conserve the probability, I unavoidably have to time the output but a constant. I believe this extra parameter leads to a poor convergence, but I have no idea how to fit the distribution in a better way.

I have looked for distribution fitting package, but those packages require a complete distribution while I only have the left side of it.

```
      x          y
1  -0.0050   0.000000
2  -0.0045  26.723019
3  -0.0040  28.557704
4  -0.0035  41.085068
5  -0.0030  66.258445
6  -0.0025  81.129807
7  -0.0020  83.751611
8  -0.0015 130.378353
9  -0.0010 157.806018
10 -0.0005 201.505657
11  0.0000 949.650354
12  0.0005 193.721270

dat<-data.frame(x=x,y=y)
res<-nls( y~(dt(x/a,df)*c), dat,
          start=list(a=0.000201, df=0.9, c=2104), trace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is symmetrical around zero? I'm asking this because points `x=0.0010`, `x=0.0015` and `x=0.0020` have much smaller `y` than `x=-0.0010`, `x=-0.0015` and `x=-0.0020`.

Comment: 0.0015 and 0.0020 have a much smaller value because of the experiment condition. I couldn't fit the distribution even without those three values. I think I should remove it from here to keep this simple. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: Maybe you should use TDist, iterate across several df and scale parameter and for each one measure the distance between your dist and the student distribution. The distribution having the lower distance (maybe square distance) from yours is the one that better describe your data.